# Remove windows 10 task bar, not auto-hide

Tags: windows, taskbar

I reallllly want to get rid of the taskbar. It takes useful screen space. Auto-hide won't cut it as it keeps popping up because of notifications and such.

Any ideas? :)

Edit: No luck, taskbar is intrinsic to explorer.exe, Taskbar Eliminator works on Windows 7, only option is to replace explorer.exe with some other shell.

thanks

Comment: See [How to completely disable the Windows 7 taskbar?](http://superuser.com/q/219605), might work for Windows 10 too.

Comment: You can stop explorer.exe from loading as suggested in the link above. This will be the best way to get rid of the taskbar, but it will also remove the desktop icons. So an alternative shell to replace it is required.

Comment: I tried the Taskbar Eliminator no luck in windows 10 :) 
Yeah I still like the desktop so I guess the only out here is to switch the explorer all together..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially taskbar is part of a component of `explorer.exe`, you can't hide the tasbar then remain the shortcut and folder on desktop, unless you have ability to mod the `explorer.exe`, or use some third party software, this is not the scope to talk in superuser.

If you dont care and want to do so, you can run `taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe` on command prompt, or make it as a startup script if you want to do it everytime when you power on the computer.

Comment: Please keep in mind, asking for software recommendations in the question or comments is offtopic. This does not mean that you are not allowed to add that in your answer or a method for finding the replacement yourself. So this is on-topic.