# How to close Windows 10 taskbar

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, taskbar

I need to install a PC with Windows 10 pro 64bit. It will be customized with a dock to launch predefined application.

How can I close (or completely hide) the windows taskbar?

I have already found several tips to audo-hide the taskbar but it does NOT work in my case since when I close an application the taskbar appears again.

I cannot close explorer.exe because I need to I need to launch an application downloaded from the Windows AppStore (for example this: https://www.microsoft.com/it-it/store/p/pressreader/9wzdncrfj13b )

In order to launch this application, I run a BAT file containing this line: C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\NewspaperDirect.PressReader_f09x14bt6ejbt!App

If I close explorer.exe this command does NOT work anymore and I cannot launch this application anymore. Furthermore, even if I close explorer.exe after launching the application, some features of that application will not work and I will not be able to close that application hence I came to the conclusion that I must close only the taskbar keeping explorer.exe alive.

At this stage, I can take into consideration also Windows registry modification to do it.

Hope you can help me Regards GP

Comment: Just use Kisok mode.

Comment: By using Kisok mode you won’t have to hide the taskbar.

Comment: Did you had a look at: https://superuser.com/questions/219605/how-to-completely-disable-the-windows-taskbar.
It is original related for Win7 but might work out for Win10 as well...

Comment: Dear all, I've been investigating on several taskbar hider apps but none of them works properly. I believe that there are 2 possibilities: creating XML file to be loaded on "Group Policies-Start layout" but I could not find how to edit the file to HIDE the taskbar. In alternative the second possibility could be creating a provisioning package to build a kiosk mode as you have suggested. I've still 2 doubts about kiosk mode: when creating a local user, the guide says that the password must be modified every 42days and the second problem is that I cannot find how to close taskbar launch UWP app.

Answer (score 0):

You only need a simple third-party program to do it.

1. Download NirCmd from [here](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html).
2. Extract the downloaded file (**nircmd-x64.zip** or **nircmd.zip**).
3. Open a command prompt window where you have extracted the contents of the file.
4. To hide the task bar, type this command: `nircmd.exe win hide class "Shell_TrayWnd"`. If you want to show the task bar, type this command: `nircmd.exe win show class "Shell_TrayWnd"`

This will hide the task bar without killing the explorer.exe process.

Comment: Dear iTechieGamer, I tried the command you suggested with nircmd but it works like other software to hide the taskbar like as "Ultimate Windows Treaker" or similar. In the beginning it hides the taskbar but when I launch applications I see that the taskbar appears again. I've contacted also the MS support and they said that the only way to close the taskbar is closing the process explorer.exe. Is the kiosk mode the ONLY alternative available?

Comment: If that happens, then you might need to kill the explorer.exe process in order to hide the taskbar fully.

Comment: If I close explorer.exe and I launch the UWT application I get the error: "explorer.exe: Class not registered"