# Limiting user privileges in an internet cafe setting

Tags: windows-7, internet, restrictions

I am trying to set up a small internet cafe with 3 PCs.

I want to make them secure and ensure that the users don't have full rights on the PC they are working on. For example, they shouldn't be able to start Task Manager, access the D: drive, or install or remove programs.

How do I configure these PCs appropriately for a cafe like this? Are there tools to make the configuration easier?

Comment: Besides *kiosk mode* for browsers, there are programs available that replace the shell and enable PCs to run in locked down kiosk mode. Can't suggest any specifically, might want to search if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc).  This tools is only available in Professional, Ultimate and Enterprise editions.  There's a [not so good explanation of it from Microsoft here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725970.aspx).  This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/254728/restrict-access-for-users-on-windows-7) may also help you as well.  You will also want to make all of your changes to a Limited User account as [Griffin](https://superuser.com/a/563139/205497) suggested.

Any tool that you end up using to do this will just be making changes to the Group Policy, so you're best off learning how to do it through Microsoft's tools.

I don't know if there are any more detailed guides out there for the tool, but I imagine there likely are for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would consult a article Microsoft published that talks a good deal about something that seems to be similar to what you want to do. This article can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee623984%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).