# windows 2012 server gpo for usb access

Tags: usb, active-directory

I face a strange problem...I need to enable usb access to a certain user..The it person responsible before me has restrictred usb access to all users by a group policy which I cannot find or investigate.
I run the gpresult and I see that only one gpo is being applied for the user I am interested in. For this specific gpo the user configuration --> administrative templates--> system _--> removable storage is all not configured..
What is going on that I am not aware of..
Thank you!

Comment: Have you added an allow exception for the USB device you want to use within the group policy?

Comment: [How to apply group policy settings to specific local accounts in Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/134066/how-to-apply-group-policy-settings-to-specific-local-accounts-in-windows) once you do that you can apply that group policy to a specific user.

Comment: it is a domain group policy and I have disabled the options specified as deny read and write access to removable storage devices under user configuration. Thank you the article I will try that suggestion as well.

Comment: But have you added an allow exception for the USB device you want to allow?  It sounds like what you have done is remove the deny exception which isn't what you want, by doing that, any user can use a USB device.

Comment: You are correct about the exception. However the configuration I have made which enables all users usb ( my first approach in investigatin0g) is not working for that particular user (windows 7). I have tested on another user account windows 8 and the user can write on the usb drive. thank you