# How to copy local group policy settings from one user account to another on the same machine?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I have a Windows 7 embeded machine that has 3 user accounts. All are required to be admin, but two of the 3 should be restricted with specific group policies. I have applied those specific group policies by following [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/134066/how-to-apply-group-policy-settings-to-specific-local-accounts-in-windows#) to account #2.

Is there a way to easily copy the policies that were applied to account #2 to account #3 without using gpedit.msc and going though each and every single one?(there are hundreds)

The end result should be that account #1 remains admin, and accounts number #2 and #3 are restricted. (account #3 is already restricted, I need to copy this to account #2 without going through every single policy again)

Comment: Check out the LGPO tool at https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/secguide/2016/01/21/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0/ but also review http://woshub.com/backupimport-local-group-policy-settings/ for more thorough detail on the process specifics.

Comment: But look over the top section of http://woshub.com/backupimport-local-group-policy-settings/ and where it states.... "***This method is quite simple, but it has some major faults:***" as this may work easily and just fine in your case in a timely manner too.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to copy the answer from the source in case it gets deleted or closed:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2030e62e-a60d-442a-8455-647b569caffb/export-import-local-group-policy-objects?forum=itproxpsp

1.) Open %systemroot%\system32\grouppolicy\

Within this folder, there are two folders - machine and user. Copy these to folders to the %systemroot%\system32\grouppolicy - folder on the target machine. Restart the machine or run GPUPDATE /force

Note :- %systemroot%\system32\grouppolicy is a hidden folder. You need to enable viewing of hidden folders in explorer.

2) Use the Security Configuration Tool
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2000/bb742512(v=technet.10)

Comment: On my system, these folders exist, but the files inside are very small, i.e. registry.pol only has 8 Bytes, so no reasonable content. The question is: if I want to store everything I can see in gpedit.msc (including all trees with all subfolders on the left side), how can all this be exported?